# Capybara can't find element if JS is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to test that a user can skip the shipping_address form after his registration.

So I have this button in the form, with some Javasrcipt that redirect to the page the user was before.

If I remove the `:js`in the scenario Capybara is able to find `#subscription` but the test fails because of the path (no js no redirection). 
If I put the`:js`it can't find the `#subscription`
Would you please give me hints for this?

**shipping_addresses/new.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Remplir plus tard', 'javascript:history.go(-1);', class: "btn btn-secondary btn-block" %>
```

**Here is the test**

```
scenario "skipping the address form for now", :js do 
    visit  root_path 
    find('#subscription').click
    choose "Monsieur"
    fill_in "user[first_name]", with: "Benoit"
    fill_in "user[last_name]", with: "Durant"
    fill_in "user[birth_date]", with: "08/05/1981"
    fill_in "user[email]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[email_confirmation]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: "password"
    fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", with: "password"

    click_on "Valider mon inscription"
    expect(page).to have_content("REMPLISSEZ VOTRE ADRESSE DE LIVRAISON")

    click_on "Remplir plus tard"

    expect(current_path).to eq root_path
end
```

**This is the dropdown in my navbar**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <%= link_to "Connection", new_user_session_path,      class: "dropdown-item"  %>
  <%= link_to "Inscription",   new_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item", id:"subscription" %>
</div>
```

## edit more of my navbar

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <% if current_user %>
              <%= current_user.first_name %>
            <% else %>
                Mon Compte
            <% end %>
          </a>
          <% if current_user %>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
             #Just removed the links to clear the code
           </div>
          <% else %>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <%= link_to "Connection", new_user_session_path,      class: "dropdown-item"  %>
              <%= link_to "Inscription",   new_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item", id:"subscription" %>
            </div>           
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the item with ID="subscription"?

Comment: it's in this link_to `<%= link_to "Inscription",   new_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item", id:"subscription" %>`

Comment: Oh I see it... you are using a drop-down menu, so the first action should be to click on the drop down menu button. But in this case, I'd just directly go to `new_user_registration_path`

Comment: It's because with JS, the button is hidden, so Capybara can't find a visible item with that ID.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just jump to the registration page directly, because the button is invisible for Capybara in the drop-down menu:

```
scenario "skipping the address form for now", :js do 
    visit   new_user_registration_path
    choose "Monsieur"
    fill_in "user[first_name]", with: "Benoit"
    fill_in "user[last_name]", with: "Durant"
    fill_in "user[birth_date]", with: "08/05/1981"
    fill_in "user[email]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[email_confirmation]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: "password"
    fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", with: "password"

    click_on "Valider mon inscription"
    expect(page).to have_content("REMPLISSEZ VOTRE ADRESSE DE LIVRAISON")

    click_on "Remplir plus tard"

    expect(current_path).to eq root_path
end
```

Alternatively you could also click on the arrow first, by giving the surrounding DIV an ID (I think... depends a bit on the CSS framework).

```
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <%= link_to "Connection", new_user_session_path,      class: "dropdown-item"  %>
  <%= link_to "Inscription",   new_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item", id:"subscription" %>
</div>
```

And do the following:

```
scenario "skipping the address form for now", :js do 
    visit  root_path 
    find('#dropdown').click
    find('#subscription').click
    choose "Monsieur"
    fill_in "user[first_name]", with: "Benoit"
    fill_in "user[last_name]", with: "Durant"
    fill_in "user[birth_date]", with: "08/05/1981"
    fill_in "user[email]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[email_confirmation]", with: "benoit@example.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: "password"
    fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", with: "password"

    click_on "Valider mon inscription"
    expect(page).to have_content("REMPLISSEZ VOTRE ADRESSE DE LIVRAISON")

    click_on "Remplir plus tard"

    expect(current_path).to eq root_path
end
```

Comment: yes that's what I had first, I wanted to the test the "long way". Btw this makes the job, not what expected but I will do this

Comment: What do you mean with the "job not what expected"? You can also give the parent <div> an ID and click on that first, if you prefer to check the long way. Let me rephrase the answer.

Comment: thanks but like this it doesn't find the `#dropdown`

Comment: What normally triggers the dropdown? I can't tell from your code.... is it a hover, or click, or...? Anyway, you should tell Capybara to take that exact same action as a user would take when you enable JS, because it tries to behave as much as an actual user as it is capable of.

Comment: @johan You didn’t answer the question - does a hover or click trigger the dropdown?

Comment: @johan, did you add the ID to the DIV?

Comment: @johan @bo-oz is correct, you need to do exactly what a user would do. In your case that means the first action on the page probably needs to be either `find('#navbarDropdownMenuLink').click` or `find('#navbarDropdownMenuLink').hover` depending on which action triggers the menu to appear.

Comment: it's a click sorry, I  will try this :)

Comment: `find('#navbarDropdownMenuLink').click ` doesn't work. `Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible css "#navbarDropdownMenuLink"`

Comment: Did you confirm that the element has an ID `navbarDropdownMenuLink`? It seems it's a different attribute `aria-labelledby`.